# What does it.test="someTest.java" and test.environment=${environment} mean in maven? Or what is the list of system properties in maven?

Tags: java, maven, junit, junit5

`-Dit.test="SomeTest.java" -Dtest.environment=${environment} ...`

What does the above values mean?

I've looked up the documentation in maven website and the explanations don't help much. I want to learn more about this but I don't know what to look for.

For example -Dit.test comes from this link.

https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/examples/single-test.html

> During development, you may run a single test class repeatedly. To run this through Maven, set the it.test property to a specific test case.

https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.6.3/maven-embedder/cli.html

This is what I found from this page.

> -D,--define    Define a system property

What's a system property? What is the list of the system properties in Maven?

Comment: A system property is a key-value structure that you can pass into the jvm from the outside world (from the commandline for example). Any java code can access these properties and thus define their own, such as the `it.test` property being used by that maven plugin. There's no global list of properties, each application may use/offer their own.

Comment: A system property isn't specific to Maven, just general Java: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html. There's no list of them because, as your example shows, a given program (like a Maven plugin) can look for whatever properties it likes.